Honojs with Vercel Middleware for Backend API
How can we use Vercel Middlware (https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-middleware/middleware-api) in a backend API developed using Hono for Vercel (https://hono.dev/docs/getting-started/vercel) ? I want to use the Vercel's middleware and then have different functions for different routes much like folder based routing that we have in Nextjs. Using Nextjs for API is too much overkill as the app becomes too big and take a lot of time to build apart from having negative impact on performance.
I tried putting middleware.js on the root of the project as suggested by Vercel but the request does not hit there at all.
